# Can Ubuntu 23.04 run on my System?

Tags: 23.04

My system specs are 4GB of RAM and a core 2 duo p8600 2.4GHz cpu. I want to ask if the ubuntu 23.04 will work with my system's specs.

Comment: If you aren't sure, just download the image, burn an installation USB and try it in live mode ("Try Ubuntu") - then you will know for sure if it works or not.

Comment: I use the following device in QA (`hp dc7900 (c2d-e8400, 4gb, intel 4 series integrated i915)`) and it runs all Ubuntu products/flavors & releases up to and including *mantic* (what will be released as 23.10).  Of note though - I'd pick based **not** on just hardware alone, but with 4GB of RAM & limited CPU, on what apps you'll use so the chosen desktop & wanted apps SHARE resources rather than need their own... and opt for a *lighter* flavor too.. as the hardware is only part of your decision.

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install works for all Ubuntu *flavors* as well; why not do that?  FYI:  I'd also consider the GPU you're using as well; as I've experienced some issues with some on specific video cards; though the *intel i915* in my example machine doesn't care - but some do.. ie. consider all aspects & not just CPU/RAM.. esp. what *apps* you'll use for best results.  Also FYI:  I used the example I copy/pasted as it was somewhat close to yours; its 1 of 27 like machines & not my lowest spec box either!